# Python: object identity question?

Tags: python, object, identity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python “is” operator behaves unexpectedly with integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/python-is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers)

```
>>>a=123
>>>b=123
>>>a is b
True
>>>id(a)==id(b)
True
```

My question is, why is id(a) the same as id(b)?.
 Aren't they two different instances of class int?

Comment: Not exact dupe.. But that question is more clear and useful.. Thanx

Comment: The following was even more surprising to me: x = "helloworld"; y = "hello" + "world"; x is y

Answer (score 3):

Usually small integers reference the same cached object in memory for efficiency purposes.

Answer (score 2):

`int`s are cached. That is an implementation detail that shouldn't matter since `int`s are immutable anyway.

Answer (score 1):

variables

```
a and b
```

both are references to the object 123 whose id is unique.

when u assign same value **123** to  two diff variables **a** and **b**,

then same object **123** is assigned to both variables **a** and **b** but reference count made to that object increases in your case refrecnce count for object **123** is **two**